# Ignore whitespace in HtmlNode.InnerText

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the HTML snippet:

```
<p>Rendered on a website, 
this will all be on one line.</p>
<p>This would be on another line.</p>
```

And the C# code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

string text = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

Now "text" will be on 3 lines:

```
Rendered on a website, 
this will all be on one line.
This would be on another line.
```

But I want:

```
Rendered on a website, this will all be on one line.
This would be on another line.
```

Is this possible using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to only add a line break after a period (`.`)? If so, and nobody else posts a good answer, you could always `Replace` all line breaks with nothing, and then `Replace` periods with periods + a line break. But that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: I don't know if this will be of any help to you, but you can try like 
`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode p = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p");

 if (p != null)
 {
  // Do something with p
 }
}`

Comment: @nbokmans Sorry for not being clear. I want to remove all line breaks inside the <p> tags, like how it would be rendered on a website. There are already line breaks between <p> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
string html = @"<p>Rendered on a website,
                this will all be on one line.</p>
                <p>This would be on another line.</p>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

string text = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");
var sentences = text.Replace(",\r\n", ", ").Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var finalText = string.Join("\r\n", sentences.Select(s => r.Replace(s, " ").Trim()));

Console.WriteLine(text + "\n");
Console.WriteLine(finalText + "\n");
```

You do not really need the Regex, I just used it to get rid of the tabular/spacing characters that were added by me hardcoding the html inside the `html` variable.

Output:

[image]